# CSP and inline scripts getting blocked

Tags: express, security, content-security-policy

Struggling with understanding CSP, getting

`Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://example;"`

Example, my domain is https://example.com,  in my policy, I have `script-src 'self' https://example;` yet inline scripts from https://example/static/js/19.b56ecbe.chunk.js is getting blocked.

I would have thought that `'self'` would allow the script to run, what am I getting wrong here?

Comment: The mention of *inline* in the message indicates the problem is inline content in the DOM of the document itself (either in the source or injected by script). So the only way you can have a CSP policy which allows that inline content is if you include the `unsafe-inline` directive. But if you’re going to add `unsafe-inline` to a policy, you might as well not using CSP at all (because `unsafe-inline` allows most of the attacks that CSP is designed to prevent).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@sideshowbarker already explained why you cannot do that but there's a little variant you can use if you want to allow "inline scripts" on your pages.

Just include `nonce` in all your `script` tags as well as in the CSP header itself.
Look here for more details: https://www.troyhunt.com/locking-down-your-website-scripts-with-csp-hashes-nonces-and-report-uri/